# Error message when posting to GMANE

Tags: gnus, email, smtpmail

When trying to post to GMANE, I get an error message:

> 441 You need a valid email address to post: Invalid response from
> SMTP server mail.inka.de: 550-Verification failed for
> auth@gmane-mx.org Couldn’t send message via news: 441 You need a
> valid email address to post: Invalid response from SMTP server
> mail.inka.de: 550-Verification failed for auth@gmane-mx.org”

Here `mail.inka.de` is the SMTP server of my provider. It looks like
something tries to connect to it with user name `auth@gmane-mx.org`.
If that is the case, then it’s no surprise that it’s not working.

My `~/.gnus.el`:

```
(setq gnus-select-method '(nntp "news.gmane.io"))
(setq user-mail-address "felix.klee@inka.de"
      message-send-mail-real-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      smtpmail-smtp-server "mail.inka.de"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 587
      smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls)
```

Emacs successfully reads my email address from the environment variable `EMAIL` and stores it in `user-mail-address`. Sending emails from GNUS works. *Why does posting to GMANE not work?*

Comment: This looks like crossed wires to my (uneducated) eyes: why does posting through  NNTP go through your SMTP mail server? Shouldn't it go directly to news.gmane.io?

Comment: Not quite sure where to start here. Gmane is a mailing list archive, which makes the mailing list available as a newsgroup. But you need to join the mailing list to post to it, even if you go through the gmane news interface. The first time you try to do so, you get a message like `Subject: Re: gmane.emacs.gnus.user: Authorization required`. You could try a different news-server just to see if you are specifying thigs correctly, for example [http://www.eternal-september.org/]

Comment: @JeffreyDeLeo The issue was a bug on GMANE's side. It has since been fixed. Maybe I should remove my question...